# Moq no longer uses return method when using sequence

Tags: moq

I have the following unit test

```
[Test]
public void FifoOrderTest()
{
    // Arrange
    var sequence = new MockSequence();
    var mockFoo1 = new Mock<IBar>();
    var mockFoo2 = new Mock<IBar>();
    mockFoo1.InSequence(sequence)
            .Setup(foo => foo.Baz)
            .Returns(100);
    mockFoo2.InSequence(sequence)
            .Setup(foo => foo.Baz)
            .Returns(10000);

    // Act
    sut.AddFoo(mockFoo1.Object);
    sut.AddFoo(mockFoo2.Object);
    sut.RunFoos();

    // Arrange
    mockFoo1.Verify(foo => foo.Something(100));
    mockFoo2.Verify(foo => foo.Something(700));
}
```

My problem is that Moq is not using the return callbacks that I set on mockFoo1 and mockFoo2. Instead when my system under test accesses the Baz property a default 0 is returned. If I remove the sequence then it once again works as expected.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a complete working example somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a method to set your Baz property a value, for example called SetProperty().

Then, try to use your foo.SetProperty instead of the property! ;) 
It will works!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your SUT is correct?

With the following SUT and IBar the test seems to work as intended:

```
public class Sut
{
    List<IBar> _barList = new List<IBar>();
    public void AddFoo(IBar bar)
    {
        _barList.Add(bar);
    }

    public void RunFoos()
    {
        foreach (var bar in _barList)
        {
            var barProperty = bar.Baz;
            if (barProperty == 100) bar.Something(100);
            if (barProperty == 10000) bar.Something(700);
        }
    }
}

public interface IBar
{
    int Baz { get; }
    void Something(int def);
}
```

I'm using Moq 4.2.1402

Note that each mock .Baz property can only be read once before the sequence steps on